# In the given figure find $\angle FBC - \angle BED$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In $\Delta ABC$, $\angle A$ = $24°$, $\angle B$ = $78°$, $D$ and $E$ are points on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively in such a way that $\angle BCD$ = $24°$, $\angle CBE$ = $51°$. $AC$ is extended to a point $F$ such that $C$ is the mid-point of $EF$. Find $
|\angle FBC – \angle BED|$.

My Work :-

Well I tried angle chasing(in figure) but to no avail.[image: figure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some calculation mistakes. $\angle ACB = 180 - 24- 78= 78=\angle ABC$. So $AB=AC$.

Also $\angle BDC = 78$. On more angle chasing, it will follow $$BC=CD=CE=CF$$

Thus $C$  is center of circle passing through $B,D,E,F$. From this it will eventually follow that $\angle FBC - \angle BED = 27$.

Comment: thnx a lot @cosmo5